# Array of objects is null after Awake() finishes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple footstep controller attached to my player object. It has a bunch of [SerializeField] that is just a bunch of footstep sounds on various surfaces.

Within my void Awake() function I call this code:

```
Debug.Log(sandClips[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, sandClips.Length)]);
```

And it properly returns one of the 4 clips in that array, with a message in the console like this:

```
footstep_sand_run_01 (UnityEngine.AudioClip)
```

But within that same file I have another function declared like this:

```
public AudioClip GetRandomClip(Vector3 location)
```

and if I try to call that exact same line of code, I get the following error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

It seems somehow I am losing that array of sounds as soon as I get out of the Awake() portion. What am I missing? I can't imagine it's anything particularly complex.

Comment: Check in the scene if you atached the script elsewhere without realising. That will have the public varibles of the script empty and might be producing the error

Comment: `UnityEngine.Random.Range` max is _inclusive_, where C#'s `Random.Next` is exclusive in the max, so maybe that is the root of the issue? I would also recommend attaching the debugger to your C# code if you haven't already, that will make it really easy to double check what Rusty mentioned

Comment: Thanks for the advice, both of you. I will check all that as soon as I get home tonight and report back if I find anything.

Comment: I've taken your suggestions and have stepped through my code and looked for scripts that might have been attached twice by accident. No such luck. I stepped through my code, and saw the arrays populated during the Awake() method but they promptly become null after it exits the Awake() function.

Comment: I still haven't been able to track down what's causing the problem. It feels like something elsewhere is resetting those Arrays to null after the scene finishes loading. As I mentioned, I can see all their values during the Awake() method but once the regular functions are called, they've lost all their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my issue though and it was really dumb I missed it.

In my FirstPersonController I instantiated a copy of my Footsteps controller class and used GetComponent() during it's Start() method. Then I just had to make sure I referenced that instantiated copy rather than whatever generic thing I was hitting.

I am still confused on how it was showing as populated during the Awake() method but it's working so all is well.